# Porting this PHP RS232 code to Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, serial-port

I'm trying to port this simple PHP script to node.js.
The TV uses RS232 and the command is PON for on; POF for off.

This example successfully turns my TV On:

```
<?php
$rs232_sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$result = socket_connect($rs232_sock, '10.0.1.155', '4999');
$rs232_in = pack("H*" ,'02'.bin2hex('PON').'03');
socket_write($rs232_sock, $rs232_in, strlen($rs232_in));
?>
```

I have this started for NodeJS:

```
var net = require('net');
var jspack = require('jspack/jspack.js').jspack;    

client.connect('4999','10.0.1.155', function(){
    console.log('CONNECTED');
        // Send the RS232 command
        client.write(jspack.Pack("H",'02'+bin2hex(command)+'03'));
}).on('data', function(data) {
    // log the response
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    // Close the connection
    client.destroy();
});
```

This is causing:

```
net.js:618
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
    ^

TypeError: invalid data
    at Socket.write (net.js:618:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/paul/Sites/homebridge-globalcache-gc100/test.js:79:10)
    at Socket.g (events.js:261:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:73:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:167:7)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1051:10)
```

Comment: I don't know much about this, but in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) the pack function accepts "H*" for a hexadecimal string, but the [jspack lib](https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack) seems to use H for unsigned short.  Pretty sure you don't want that.  "s" or "c" perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extra libraries to send binary data. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
var net = require('net');
var PON_MSG = new Buffer('\x02PON\x03', 'binary');
var POF_MSG = new Buffer('\x02POF\x03', 'binary');

client.connect('4999','10.0.1.155', function() {
  console.log('CONNECTED');
  // Replace `PON_MSG` with `POF_MSG` to do POF instead
  client.write(PON_MSG);
}).on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('DATA: %j', data);
});
```

Also be aware that the `data` event can fire multiple times, so when you can safely end the connection (if the remote side doesn't do so automatically) depends on the protocol (to make sure you have received the entire response).